# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated error at the end of ajax call

Tags: ajax, forms

I'm a developer on a freelancing site (the only one actually) and I'm trying to allow anonymous users to bid on a project too. For this reason, I have the following code to check whether the username the anonymous user typed exists in the database, and show them a warning if it does. Now, everything works great, except that if the username exists in the database, I get the error at the end of the post and we can't check again because all Javascript executing is halted. What am I missing?

```
function tubitekuz_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id) {
    case 'webform_client_form_97':
      $form['submitted']['kullanici_adi']['#ajax'] = array(
        'wrapper' => 'webform-client-form',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'effect' => 'fade',
        'event' => 'blur',
        'async' => 'false',
        'callback' => '_tubitekuz_check_username',
      );
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

function _tubitekuz_check_username($form, &$form_state) {
  $parents = $form_state['triggering_element']['#array_parents'];
  array_pop($parents);
  $element = &drupal_array_get_nested_value($form, $parents);
  $exists = FALSE;
  $username = $form_state['values']['submitted']['kullanici_adi'];
  if (!empty($username)) {
    $exists = user_load_by_name($username);
  }
  if ($exists) {
    form_error($element, 'Kullanıcı adı kayıtlı, lütfen başka bir kullanıcı adı seçin');
    $error_selector = '.webform-client-form';
    $commands[] = ajax_command_replace($error_selector, theme('status_messages').drupal_render($form));
    return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
  }
}
```

**The error**

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

Comment: It's complaining about `'async' => 'false'`, that's being phased out. Not good to block the UI thread

Comment: Thought of that, and set it to true. Didn't matter

Comment: Something else is doing the same thing in that case, the warning means that a blocking xmlhttprequest was made which you won't be able to do in the future. Check the network tab in dev tools to see the request/response, the payload should give you clues about which process is causing it

Comment: All I see is `ajax`, `jquery-validator.js` and some image.

Comment: Okay, I disabled jquery-validator and I'm not getting the error now, but Javascript executing still halts.

Comment: Reproduced your solution and it works. Don't know what may be a problem. Used async - true, also enabled webform_ajax module and enabled "AJAX mode" oprion in webform settings.

Comment: I enabled webform_ajax and AJAX mode in webform settings, no dice. Then I started playing around and found the solution. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I at least found a solution. What I did was add the below again to my webform's tpl file, because that was the one which had stopped working.

```
$(".messages").on("click", function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Messages elements stopped JS?

Comment: Yes, I don't know why.

Comment: Mb something with jquery version?

Comment: I don't think so, everything else worked smoothly.

Comment: I can accept in 2 days.